# What are distinguishable terms in Bohm theorem?

Tags: lambda-calculus

I have just started to study "Lambda-Calculus and Combinators, an Introduction" by Roger Hindley.

There is a formulation of B ̈ohm’s theorem that I can not understand.

[image]

$M$ and $N$ are terms in bn-normal form. Based on the description I assume that $M$ could be equal to λ-term $x$ and $N=y$. $x≠y$. Both $x$ and $y$ do not have b-redexes and n-redexes.
I do not understand how to distinguish between $M=x$ and $N=y$.

$xL_1..L_nxy => x$

$yL_1..L_nxy => y$

[image]

[image]

I have found another formulation of this theorem where everything is clear.
A function is applied to terms rather than terms ($M$ and $N$) are applied to combinators.

[image]

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: What are $L_0, L_1,...$ to distinguish $x$ and $y$?

Comment: Please don't write your question or put clarifications in the comments.  Instead, [edit] the question to incorporate all relevant information in the question, and make sure it reads well for someone who encounters it for the first time.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe the word "combinator" in your first statement of Böhm's theorem means a *closed* λ-term, i.e. one which has no free variables (as is the case [here](https://cs.stackexchange.com/a/68971/154866) for instance); this is consistent with the fact that the statement at the end of your question mentions *closed* normal forms. Thus your example terms $M$ and $N$ are not combinators because $fv(M) = \{x\}$ and $fv(N) = \{y\}$, so they don't satisfy the assumption of Böhm's theorem.